# spark creat output folder before saveastext

Tags: java, apache-spark

I wrote a spark programme, and it do two main jobs.

1:Based on the source RDD Entity, calculate a string set named tagset, and rdd.collect() to the driver, then make it a broadcast variable;

2:Based on the source RDD Entity, and do some map function based on the tagset above, and then save the output rdd into the hdfs path;

Some code snippet:
1.

```
  JavaRdd<Entity> source = ....;
  Set<String> tag_set = JavaRdd<Entity>.map(...).keyBy(...).reduceByKey(...).collectAsMap().keySet();
  Broadcast<Set<String>> global_tag_set = sparkContext.broadcast(tag_set);
```

2.do some transformation on source rdd using the broadcast string set:

```
source.map(
     .....
     if(global_tag_set.getValue().contains(e.getLable())
     .....
  ).saveAsText(outputpath);
```

While I run the programme above, I the **Problem One**:

```
FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://...outputpath already exists.I am surely cleaned the outputpath before running it.
```

Then I add some clean job before the saveAsText:

```
JavaRDD<String> r = source.map(
     .....
     if(global_tag_set.getValue().contains(e.getLable())
     .....
  );
 FileSystem f= ...;
 f.delete(new Path(outputpath), true);
 r.saveAsText(outputpath));
```

I get another exception, **Problem Two**:

```
java.lang.unsupportedOperationException:...
```

and in the stack trace there exists some tips for my java code position,just point to the code using braodcast varialbe：

```
if(global_tag_set.getValue().contains(e.getLable())
```

and If I do make tag_set a broadcast variable, the I get **Problem Three:**

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.AbstractMap$1
-object not serializable....vale: ....
-filed(...,name: tag_set,type : interface java.util.set)
```

Why, how can I resolve these problem?Why does these problems happen?

Comment: I fixed the problem by make the tag_set as a HashSet<String> varaible.But there also exists the problem: 1.Why the output path created before saveastext() invoked! 2.How to use the broadcast variable in programme?